# Probability of tie in $4$-game series

Tags: probability

The Mustangs and Tigers are scheduled to play a 4-game series. The probability that the Mustangs will win any single game is $60\%$, while the probability that the Tigers will win any single game is $30\%$. What is the probability that the series as a whole will be a tie?

My approach:
If there is a for a single game, then both the Mustangs and Tigers must "loose" separately. This means that the probability of a tie is $(1-.6)(1-.3) = \frac{7}{25}$

Therefore, four ties in a row must have the probability of
$$(\frac{7}{28})^4 = \frac{2401}{390625}$$

Is my approach correct? The probability I came up with seems bizarrely low.

Comment: Is that a Duel? i.e., do they play each other? In that case, a single game can end in a tie (with a probability of $10\%$). Is that correct?

Comment: They play each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mustangs must either

1. win twice and lose twice
2. win once , lose once, two draws
3. 4 draws

These cases are incompatible.

For case $1$, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ victories out of $4$ games. The two remaining games must be lost, that gives us a total of  $\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}=6$. Each of these scenarios has a probability to occur equals to $$0.6*0.6*0.3*0.3$$

The probability that case $1$ occurs is  $$6*0.6*0.6*0.3*0.3=0.1944$$

For case 2, we must pick one victory and one loss, the rest are draws, therefore we have $\binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}=12$ scenarios possible. Each of these scenarios has a probability to occur equals to $$0.6*0.3*0.1*0.1$$

The probability that case $2$ occurs is  $$12*0.6*0.3*0.1*0.1=0.216$$

For case 3, we have one possibility : 4 draws , and it has a probability to occur equals to $0.1^4$

The final probability is $$0.1944+0.216+0.0001=0.2161$$

Answer (score 0):

We note that 
$$P(M) = 0.6, \ P(T) = 0.3, \ \mbox{ and so } \  P(\mbox{a tie}) = 0.1.$$

We assume that any two distinct games are independent.

Now the series can end in a tie in the following mutually exclusive ways.

1. Two wins each for both $M$ and $T$: Probability $$= 6 (0.6)^2 (0.3)^2 = 0.1944.$$ The integer multiple $6$ is the total number of all possible combinations of the two games won by $M$ (or $T$).
2. One win each for both $M$ and $T$ and two ties: Probability $$= 12 (0.6)(0.3)(0.1)^2 = 0.0216.$$ The number of combinations of the two tied games out of $4$ is  ${4 \choose 2} = 6$, corresponding to each of which $M$ has $2$ choices of winning a game. Thus there are a total of $$6 \times 2 = 12$$ possibilities.
3. All four ties: Probability $$= (0.1)^4 = 0.0001.$$

So the Total Probability of a tied 4-game series $$= 0.1944 + 0.0216 + 0.0001 = 0.2161 = \frac{2161}{10000}.$$

Hope this solution is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution says that the probability is $\frac{2161}{10000}$

Comment: @IanLimarta have a look at my answer now. I've editted the solution to remove an error.